# Django : Page Not found

Tags: python, django

Im foraying into the world of django and following the tutorial from [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/setup.html#testing-your-setup). However I keep getting a 404 page not found error when I try creating the basic `view`.

I used the `django-admin.py` command and created a folder named `Project`. Which in turn has a folder the the same name( ill call it subProject here to avoid confusion) and the `manage.py` file. The subProject has the files

```
1.init.py
2.settings.py
3.urls.py
4.wsgi.py
```

I then created an app folder in Project called `rango`. Rango has the `init.py, views,py, tests.py models.py and views.py` files.

i only edited the `views` and the `urls` file. they are as follows:

`/rango/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
     return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

`/rango.urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))
```

I then edited the `urls.py` in subProject

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
)
```

I added the add in the setting file. However when i do `python manage.py runserver` and go to the project URL it says

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^rango/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Ive followed the tutorial as it is. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't specified root url in your urls.py

you can access

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango
```

but not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. In order to access the root URL,

put `url(r'^$', 'rango.views.index', name='index')` in urls.py

Comment: In which file do i paste this into? The url file in rango or the subProject?

Comment: urls.py in subProject

Comment: Oh it works! I had to remove the `url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls'))` line .

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I think that you need the HTML file to access it online. For example, in the Learning Log project by Eric Matthes, you had to make the HTML "topic" file in order to do localhost:8000/topic/1

Comment: From Review: "I'm having this problem too" is not a valid answer in S.O. rules. Please post this as a comment to the question.